# How to signup to run a code after the name/method has been defined using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, uniform

I am trying to run a code but I get

```
$.uniform is undefined
[Break on this error] $.uniform.restore("#f_variedbyoperator");
```

How can I use jQuery, to detect if `.uniform` has been defined? And to signup the code to run after that.

Comment: Please post your code so we can see what you're attempting.

Comment: It's there. I want to run `$.uniform.restore("#f_variedbyoperator"); ` but $.uniform has not yet been defined.

Comment: It sounds like your script order is off, is this plugin being fetched asynchronously?

Comment: Yes, I want to issue a restore of the effect, after has been loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same way you'd test any other property:

- `$.hasOwnProperty('uniform')` (true if it **is** defined), or
- `typeof $.uniform === 'undefined'` (true if it **is not** defined), or
- `!!$.uniform` (true if it is a truthy value - anything other than `undefined`, `null`, `0`, `false`, or `''` - the empty string)

What do you mean "signup the code to run?"

---

```
var i = setInterval(function ()
{
    if ($.uniform)
    {
        clearInterval(i);
        $.uniform.restore("#f_variedbyoperator");
    }
}, 1000); // check for $.uniform every 1000 ms
```

Comment: I want to run `$.uniform.restore("#f_variedbyoperator"); ` subscribed by some event after `$.uniform` has been defined.

Comment: @Pentium10: I assume you mean something like a repeated check, until it exists. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is check that an element exists, try:

```
if($('element').length)
{
  // exists!
}
```

Comment: Not my down-vote (I'm anticipating this getting one), but this is *completely* unrelated to the question.

Comment: He asked how to check if an element was defined. This is how. The question is confusing as it is. That's why I prefaced the answer with "if..."

Comment: He wasn't asking about an element at all, the word "element" appears nowhere in the question :)

Comment: Right, that's what I get for reading a question too quickly and answering with a lack of sleep. Now that I reread it, it's clear I misinterpreted it. Mea culpa.